# previous tasks results to send mail on failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have dts package in 2008. It was a ftp task and a mail task. i want to send an email with the task execution results (exact error messages)

Is there a way to receive previous task's error codes/messages in the send email task?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the error and message of the previous step from the [`sysjobhistory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174997.aspx) table. You need to know your own job id (eg. look it up by name in [`syjobs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189817.aspx)).